# Compiling and Running Dynamically creating C Program on Android NDK

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, apk

Is it possible to create an Android NDK project for compiling and running a C program which can be create dynamically?

I am trying to develop an Android application to compile and run c program, which is typed by the user in a text box or text-area.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Android devices do not ship with a C compiler by default, but you could certainly provide your own.  How complex of a program were you hoping to handle?

Comment: not much complex simple programming, that all.... @fadden as you said is there is a way to add out own compiler? Then how NDK works ?

Comment: @fadden as you said is there is a way to add any compiler to run c programs? Then what is the use of NDK, and how its work ?

Answer (score -1):

See https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.n0n3m4.droidc. Is your idea very different? Note that **gcc** or alternatives use GPL which restricts your freedom to make money off this initiative.